# Forward a bunch of emails individually out of Apple Mail

Tags: mail.app, email

I'm  using Zapier to parse ~1000 emails I have in a folder on Apple Mail. I have set up a Zapier parsing template using 1 sample email. To my knowledge, the next step is to forward the 1000 emails from Apple Mail to Zapier's specified parsing mailbox.

But I have to forward these individually, like basically I need to forward 1000 emails, rather than 1 email with 1000 emails wrapped up into it.

How do I do this? In Apple Mail, if I Select All and forward, it sends 1 email with 1000 emails wrapped up into it, which isn't what I want. If I create a rule, it only applies to future emails, not retroactively to the emails I have already saved in this folder.

Thanks

Comment: If you right-click/control-click/two-finger-tap on a message to open a context menu for the message, one of the options is *Apply Rules.* Can you select all the messages and choose the *Apply Rules* option to use the rule you mention in your third paragraph?

Comment: @jefe2000 so i think it could work but I'm getting some very weird behavior. in my inbox, as a very loose test, I create a filter for EVERY message, to forward to a specific mailbox, I save it, and it asks me if I want to apply it to all selected messages. I think... of course! But somehow only 2 emails get sent (only 2 of the selected messages get forward). And it's the same 2 each time I try to make any rule it seems...

Comment: @jefe2000 forwarding rule apparently has issues working that other people have noted: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250039723